# Which mathematics library to chose to convert LabView blocks

Tags: c++, math

I'm looking for the best choice of C++ Mathematics library to make easier some operations from LabView blocks.

I need to realize many complex mathematics things on C++ alike: linear regression, peak detection, derivative for the graph and many others alike.

I found there are a lot of libraries for it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries#C_and_C.2B.2B

Which library is better to chose for my tasks?

(currently Im thinking about boost BLAS but I never worked with it earlier so maybe this choice is wrong)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that there isn't much more to boost uBLAS than basic linear algebra; and even if you consider the larger boost "[Math and Numerics"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/?view=category_Math) section, it can hardly be considered a complete scientific computing package.

[GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) is very good in that it's quite [comprehensive](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/).  However, it's very much a 'C' library so you need to be prepared to work with raw pointers to array data and function pointer callbacks rather than higher level classes.

(Personally these days I find myself using Python/Numpy/Scipy as much as possible; the scope of Scipy is [truly incredible](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.10.1/reference/) and Numpy arrays are fantastically easy to work with; if there was a LabView/Python/Scipy integration that met any other requirements it'd be the first thing I'd be looking it).

Comment: @Alessa: note for future: if you have constraints on licensing, it's a good idea to list them in the original question!  The only other large, comperehensive collection of numerics code I've used is from the Numerical Recipes book http://www.nr.com/ which I believe can be licensed for commercial use http://www.nr.com/licenses/ .  The code's Fortran roots (1 indexed arrays) makes it slightly annoying for people used to 'C' but it's all good stuff otherwise.